# Hibernate dynamicupdate performance for big table and small tables

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a huge mysql table in my project. I use hibernate in my Java EE project. The table structure is as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `syncdirectionanddate` 
(
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   accountsModifiedFromDate DATETIME,
   accountsModifiedToDate DATETIME,
   accountsModifiedCurrentDate DATETIME,
   accountsModifiedFromPage int,
   accountsModifiedCurrentPage int,
   customerModifiedFromDate DATETIME,
   customerModifiedToDate DATETIME,
   customerModifiedCurrentDate DATETIME,
   customerAndAccountsSyncDirection int,
   productsModifiedFromDate DATETIME,
   productsModifiedToDate DATETIME,
   productsModifiedCurrentDate DATETIME,
   productsModifiedFromPage int,
   productsModifiedCurrentPage int,
   itemInventoryModifiedFromDate DATETIME,
   itemInventoryModifiedToDate DATETIME,
   itemInventoryModifiedCurrentDate DATETIME,
   itemInventoryAndProductsSyncDirection int,
   itemNonInventoryModifiedFromDate DATETIME,
   itemNonInventoryModifiedToDate DATETIME,
   itemNonInventoryModifiedCurrentDate DATETIME,
   itemNonInventoryAndProductsSyncDirection int,
   itemServiceModifiedFromDate DATETIME,
   itemServiceModifiedToDate DATETIME,
   itemServiceModifiedCurrentDate DATETIME,
   itemServiceAndProductsSyncDirection int,
   itemDiscountModifiedFromDate DATETIME,
   itemDiscountModifiedToDate DATETIME,
   itemDiscountModifiedCurrentDate DATETIME,
   itemDiscountAndProductsSyncDirection int,
   itemGroupModifiedFromDate DATETIME,
   itemGroupModifiedToDate DATETIME,
   itemGroupModifiedCurrentDate DATETIME,
   itemGroupAndProductsSyncDirection int,
   itemOtherChargeModifiedFromDate DATETIME,
   itemOtherChargeModifiedToDate DATETIME,
   itemOtherChargeModifiedCurrentDate DATETIME,
   itemOtherChargeAndProductsSyncDirection int,
   itemSalesTaxModifiedFromDate DATETIME,
   itemSalesTaxModifiedToDate DATETIME,
   itemSalesTaxModifiedCurrentDate DATETIME,
   itemSalesTaxAndProductsSyncDirection int,
   contactsModifiedFromDate DATETIME,
   contactsModifiedToDate DATETIME,
   contactsModifiedCurrentDate DATETIME,
   contactsModifiedFromPage int,
   contactsModifiedCurrentPage int,
   invoiceQBModifiedFromDate DATETIME,
   invoiceQBModifiedToDate DATETIME,
   invoiceQBModifiedCurrentDate DATETIME,
   invoicesZohoModifiedFromDate DATETIME,
   invoicesZohoModifiedToDate DATETIME,
   invoicesZohoModifiedCurrentDate DATETIME,
   invoicesZohoModifiedFromPage int,
   invoicesZohoModifiedCurrentPage int,
   invoiceQBinvoicesZohoSyncDirection int,
   vendorQBModifiedFromDate DATETIME,
   vendorQBModifiedToDate DATETIME,
   vendorQBModifiedCurrentDate DATETIME,
   vendorsZohoModifiedFromDate DATETIME,
   vendorsZohoModifiedToDate DATETIME,
   vendorsZohoModifiedCurrentDate DATETIME,
   vendorsZohoModifiedFromPage int,
   vendorsZohoModifiedCurrentPage int,
   vendorQBvendorsZohoSyncDirection int,
   customerMapping varchar(50),
   PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
);
```

This table needs very frequent updates and only 2 or 3 columns have to be updated at time. My question is : should I keep this big table and use @dynamicupdate in hibernate or divide this table in smaller tables and not use dynamicupdates. I do not mind 1 table or many tables. I just want to know what will be the performance of both the approach.

Comment: Test both approaches and you will know the answer.

Comment: How testing can be done ?

Comment: Set up the code and the database both ways, then simulate the insertion or update of lots of data.

Comment: If you are asking this question, you likely are not working with enough data for it to matter. Shadow is right that the only way is to test it in your environment, with your expected volume of data.

Comment: There are a lot of MySQL experts here, but not many Hibernate experts.  Please explain what "@dynammicupdate in hibernate" is.

Comment: How many such Updates occur per second?  I suggest that MySQL can handle 100 single-row, `UPDATE ... WHERE username = '...'` statements per second on HDD.  More on SSD.

Comment: A normal Hibernate update will set all columns, even if the values did not change, to improve statement/cursor cache hits. A dynamic update will only mention columns in the SQL SET clause that have actually changed the value. I don't know what MySQL does behind the scenes, but I would be interested to know :)